# Regex for Commonwealth Legal Citations

Tags: regex, perl

I need a regex expression to capture multiple citations from a string.

**Examples of the raw text:**

**In a numbered list**

1. Out of Pocket Expenses incurred by Third Parties:  Schneider v Eisovitch [1960] 2 QB 430

**Multiple citations in one line**

Loss directly consequent to a divorce: Jones v Jones [1985] QB 704.  However, see Pritchard v J H Cobden Ltd [1988] Fam 22.

The general format of the citation

PartyName1 v [PartyName2 [Year] [Number of Volume] {String of Characters for Volume Identification} [Page Number]

**So the citations will look like this**

Schneider v Eisovitch [1960] 2 QB 430

Pritchard v J H Cobden Ltd [1988] Fam 22

**Usage**

I'm just learning Perl so I'm trying to figure out what the best way to utilize regex for this is.

I'm also considering using Biblio Citation Parser - Still playing around with it.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Biblio::Citation::Parser::Standard](http://metacpan.org/pod/Biblio%3a%3aCitation%3a%3aParser%3a%3aStandard)

Comment: If you need a regular expression, you should write one.  Or [hire a programmer](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/checkout/listing/choose).  When you have a RegEx for us to help you with, you should tell us [what you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com), and probably provide us with a [short, self contained, compileable example](http://sscce.org).  Or - you can always read the [SO "How to Ask" page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would recommend you try using the existing module first and only start writing your own solution if it turns out that it doesn't meet your requirements. Using regexes to parse anything other than very well defined formats can get pretty complex and have lots of subtle gotchas. Chances are the module authors will already have had to deal with these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any certainty, you can try this pattern:

```
(?>[A-Z]['\pL]*\s+)+v\s+(?>[A-Z]['\pL]*\s+)+\[\d{4}]\s+[^\r\n.]++
```

Comment: With out any certainty, you could also use `.*`...

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: Why not! :), but I am not sure this will match the example strings.